# select child of parent element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select one div with ('.nav-dropdown-content') class in parent with  ('.nav-dropdown') class to add .active class on the that child look at my code
my function doesn't work correctly how can I select that child?

```
<div class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Parent</a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var navDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-dropdown');
for (let i = 0 ; i < navDropDown.length ; i++) {
    navDropDown[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        navDropDown[i].lastChild.addEventListener.classList.toggle('active');
    })
}
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: `lastChild.addEventListener.classList` makes no sense. `addEventListener` is a function -- it does not have a `classList` property.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a long series of words that could use some splitting into sentences.

Comment: @trincot how can I select that child to have .nav-dropdown-content class?

Comment: @trincot My English is poor, I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick that last element, attach a listener to it, toggle the class

```js
document.querySelector('.nav-dropdown-content:last-child')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  })
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Parent</a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need: `navDropDown[i].lastElementChild.classList.toggle('active');`

So you can toglle the inner DIV with active class by clicking on the outer DIV

```js
var navDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-dropdown');
for (let i = 0 ; i < navDropDown.length ; i++) {
    navDropDown[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        navDropDown[i].lastElementChild.classList.toggle('active');
    })
}
```

```css
.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Parent</a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Soooooo Much my friend :x